# Read CSV file Linq

Tags: c#, linq

My data is as follows,

Name,Birthdate,Location,Qualification
"Ranjan,Priya",01/01/1988,"Pune,Maharashtra",B.Tech
"Mayank,Agrawal",05/05/1990,"Ranchi,Rajsthan",BCA

When i am using split property and comma as delimiter my name and location values gets splited but its a single value.Then how to get Name and Location as single value using linq.

Comment: It's hopeless to try LINQ at parsing a fill-blown CSV. You can get a free reader instead (here is the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)).

Comment: There might be a way to deal with this case by applying a regex. But, before we dig into it, just to be sure: can't you create the CSV file using another separator (such as semicolon or pipe)?

Comment: We've used LinqToCsv in production for a couple years now. Works great. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't really go with Linq on this one. RegEx is a much more natural fit and, bonus, this problem has been [solved by others](http://geekswithblogs.net/mwatson/archive/2004/09/04/10658.aspx). That's where I found this:

```
  protected virtual string[] SplitCSV(string line)
  {         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options = ((System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline) 
        | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     Regex reg = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\\\"(?:[^\\\"]+|\\\"\\\")*\\\"|[^,]*)", options);
     MatchCollection coll = reg.Matches(line);
     string[] items = new string[coll.Count];
     int i = 0;
     foreach(Match m in coll)
     {
        items[i++] = m.Groups[0].Value.Trim('"').Trim(',').Trim('"').Trim();
     }
     return items;
  }
```